# Check if a key in WPF OnKeyUp event is a special character

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

I've created a OnKeyUp method to RichTextControl, and I want to ignore all keys, which are special characters (like shift, control, alt etc).

One way to do that is to enumerate all the characters that I want to ignore, but I'm wondering, if there's something like IsSpecialKey function somewhere, that I can use in this context

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813389/how-to-capture-ctrltab-ctrlshifttab-in-wpf

Comment: I don't want to capchure a key. I want to check if my key belongs to array of special keys, like shift, alt win etc. Those aren't exactly the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the [Char.IsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18zw7440.aspx) method on the [KeyCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keycode.aspx) property of the [KeyEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1660kh1c.aspx) like this:

```
KeysConverter kc = new KeysConverter();
if (!Char.IsControl(Convert.ToChar(kc.ConvertToString(e.KeyCode))))
{
    ...
}
```