# WPF handle shortcut inside TabControl (CTRL+F search)

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to handle *Ctrl+F* keys combo to invoke search function inside my `TabControl`.

`OnKeyDown()` called for each button pressed, but how I can handle combination of two buttons?

Comment: Check Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) (and right). However you should use command binding for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture Ctrl + Tab and Ctrl + Shift + Tab in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813389/how-to-capture-ctrl-tab-and-ctrl-shift-tab-in-wpf)

Comment: Could you put my put my answer as checked please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put this in your xaml :

```
<Window.InputBindings>
 <KeyBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.YourCommandToHandle"
       Gesture="CTRL+F" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Comment: My Window have 3 tabs, I need this shortcut only on one of them.
Is it possible?

Comment: Yes indeed you can. I can see two solution to my mind.
You can make a binding between your SelectedItem in your TabControl and CanExecute in your Command through a converter. Else you can put a condition on the SelectedItem in your Command (by its key or what so ever), but it's not really MVVM.